# Reducing Quadratic form

Tags: quadratic-forms

Reduce the quadratic form to a canonical form and find the rank index and signature. Write down the corresponding equations of transformation:

$$ 4x_1^2 + 3x_2^2 - x_3^2 + 2x_2 x_3 - 4x_3 x_1 + 4x_1 x_2 $$

The given solution says:
$(w1)^2 + (w2)^2 - (w3)^2 ;$
$r=3, p=2, s=1;$
$x_1 = (1/2)(w_1) - (\sqrt 2/4)(w_2) + (1/2)(w_3),$
$x_2 = (\sqrt 2/2)(w_2) - (1/2)(w_3),$
$x_3 = (1/2)(w_3)$

Can anyone provide with detailed ans,how they come up with this?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you already look here at this site, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2874040/finding-rank-and-signature-of-a-quadratic-form), or  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1271406/reduction-of-quadratic-forms) etc.?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Despite voting to close your Question as a duplicate, I have improved the formatting to show you how $\LaTeX$ and `MarkDown` can be used to make such posts more legible.  Please review my edit, both to check that I did not unintentionally change your meaning and to gather an idea how to use [math notation here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) in the future.